# Django Cassandra sync_cassandra not syncing models

Tags: python, django, web, cassandra

I created an app named "Example" then copy and pasted example code given docs.

App create code:

```
python manage.py startapp Example
```

in Example/models.py:

```
import uuid
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from django_cassandra_engine.models import DjangoCassandraModel
class ExampleModel(DjangoCassandraModel):
  example_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
  example_type = columns.Integer(index=True)
  created_at = columns.DateTime()
  description = columns.Text(required=False)
```

when ı write this to console.. it only creates keyspace.. Not syncing model..

```
python manage.py sync_cassandra
```

Why it not syncing model to database? İt creates keyspace?